# Is it possible to apply texture on every object in a image

Tags: texturing

Here is the picture (randomly chosen):

[image: reference image of a room]

And here is the texture:

[image: texture]

Is it possible to apply this texture to the surface of every object?

Comment: Like I said [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105060/how-to-add-same-texture-to-multiple-objects-at-once-with-python#comment185747_105060) "How are you going to map this texture? Are these separate objects, or all in one mesh?" Also what render engine are you going to use?

Comment: @David In one mesh

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if all of them have UV coordinates then you can make a material that uses UV coordinates to map the image. If not, you can use a material that uses generated coordinates (if in Cycles, maybe use Box mapping) and then you can mention that material in the over ride field in the Render Layers dialog.
[image: override]

edit: I had assumed you meant objects created, but now I realize you might be talking about a found picture - in this sense, you would have to model proxies for every object and use material(s) that share that image texture.